# How to access mysql with asking the root password

Tags: mysql, database

I have installed MySQL community edition in the  Centos machine, I want to access the MySQL service by just typing `mysql` instead of `mysql -uroot -p<password>`, I have done so sort configuration adding the username and password in the `my.cnf` that is not gone work anymore it throwing

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

Answer (score 1):

```
As error is defined ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES), you are using the wrong password for accessing mysql.
You can also update username & password using cli 
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root'; & restart mysql using sudo service mysql restart

Thanks
```